# Android view gesture rotation with "ease" and fixed degrees

Tags: java, android, rotation, gesture

I am trying to develope a wheel like  main menu activity by using [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/) example but i want to make this spinning view  stop at  only 36 degree and its multipliers(i will put 10 items(buttons) on the circle by dividing it 10 equal parts).I tried to implement pid controller algorithm but couldn't manage it.please someone point me to right direction to do this.Thanks(sorry for my deficient English)

I  want this wheel stop like the android gallery.

Comment: Find a simpler implementation, the source you have pointed is some sort of tragedy. People build 3D spinners with less code than that... I wish you good luck and success.